# Is there a way to customize the file browser in google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, google-chrome-devtools

It has such a plain white background and it looks like it's from the 90s. Is there an extension or easy hack to make it sleeker?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a chrome extension that gave me the sleek, dark look I wanted if anyone cares. [Here is the link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/plpngdlpkpapinbbheohgcgpikiepfge/publish-accepted?authuser=3)